# Activity should run only once at the first run of the App in phone

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have created an activity named activity_create_password which will create password for the app when the application is started on the cell for the first time and next time onwards it should show the activity named activity_insert_password. how can I achieve this I am not getting Please Help.

Comment: Store a flag into preferences like `isFirstRun` which will be `true` by default. After first run change value to `false`. And in each lunch you should check value of this variable. And show/ skip Activity depends on value.

Comment: use shared preference..
create 2 page activity_create_password and activity_insert_password and check for first time run then show activity_create_password page else activity_insert_password page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `SharedPreferences` to achieve this, your code should be something like

```
SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("appName", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
Intent intent;
if (prefs.getBoolean("isInitialAppLaunch", false))
{
    intent = new Intent(this, activity_insert_password.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
    //First Time App launched, you are putting isInitialAppLaunch to false and calling create password activity.
    editor.putBoolean("isInitialAppLaunch", false);
    intent = new Intent(this, activity_create_password.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SharedPreferences class to achieve this.

See the below link to use shared preference.

[How to use shared preferences](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)